# protobuf-net exception: No serializer defined for type: System.Xml.XmlDocument

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

How to serialize an object which contains property of XmlDocument type?:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Foo
{
    [ProtoMember(1)] 
    public XmlDocument Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As a string; for example:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Foo
{
    public XmlDocument Bar { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    private string BarSerialized {
        get { return Bar == null ? null : Bar.OuterXml; }
        set {
            if (value == null) { Bar = null; }
            else {
                var tmp = new XmlDocument();
                tmp.LoadXml(value);
                Bar = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I guess this *could* be handled automatically, but... packing xml inside protobuf already seems to smell a bit of redundancy / inner-platform-effect. I As such, I'm not sure that it is something I want to *encourage* by adding direct library support ;p

If you have *lots* of xml-documents in your model, then - well, *firstly* protobuf probably isn't going to gain you much, but secondly : it is probably possible to hook a "surrogate" for `XmlDocument` in v2; this will probably add 2 bytes overhead per doc, but if you have xml that probably isn't your biggest problem.